# How to show users information about extension updates, redirect to a url after update or other methods

Tags: google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

In the past, I've seen other extensions be able to redirect you to an info page after the update is completed. I will soon be releasing an update and would like to inform users as soon as the update is completed. Not after they click the icon.

I came across update_info_url which can be placed in the manifest.json however it is unclear if it has been depreciated or not

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/Updates#Update_objects

All other google results date back to 2009.

I'm just trying to figure out how to go about this, i believe I definitely have seen other extensions achieve this.

Comment: You can use [chrome.runtime.onInstalled](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onInstalled) listener

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in the background script:

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(details => {
    if (details.reason == 'update'){
        chrome.tabs.create({url:'https://example.com/extensionupdated.html'});
    }
});
```